# Why gcc (ARM) aren't using Global Register Variables as source operands?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, cpu-registers

here is a c source code example:

```
register int a asm("r8");
register int b asm("r9");

int main() {
    int c;
    a=2;
    b=3;
    c=a+b;
    return c;
}
```

And this is the assembled code generated using a arm gcc cross compiler:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -c global_reg_var_test.c -Wa,-a,-ad

...
mov     r8, #2
mov     r9, #3
mov     r2, r8
mov     r3, r9
add     r3, r2, r3
...
```

When using -frename-registers, the behaviour was the same. (updated. Before I had said with -O3.)

So the question is: why gcc add the 3rd and 4th MOV's instead of 'ADD R3, R8, R9'?

Context: I need to optimize a code in a simulated inorder cpu (gem5 arm minorcpu) that doesn't rename registers.

Comment: strangely GCC decided not to return 5 directly.

Comment: @user3528438: For me it does `movs    r0, #5; bx      lr`.

Comment: ths observation about -O3 was used with another code, resulting the extra MOVs.. With this code it returned 5 directly.

Comment: @GermanoAndersson: Can you produce a better testcase? It's a bit hard to argue that gcc doesn't optimize this well when I can only see this behavior for `gcc -O0`.

Comment: If you need better optimization than GCC can provide you're going to have write custom assembly. Trying to force it into using certain registers isn't going to work. The whole `register asm("")` thing is a legacy from ancient versions of the compiler that used a much simpler register allocator.

Comment: Most ARM cores don't reorder registers. Just use the correct target architecture. In general it is a bad idea to outwit your compiler. What code do you get without interfering with the optimizer?

Comment: What microarchitecture are you tuning for at -O3? I can't imagine something else simple and in-order would be all that far off - e.g. ARM7/9/10, perhaps 1136 or Cortex-A5 too.

Comment: @Notlikethat: Not to forget ARMv6M and v7M, v7R, etc.

Comment: To be nitpicky: This code isn't using "global" register variables (as the title implies), since they aren't declared at global scope.  When declared within a function like this, they are "local register variables."  And yes, there are some differences.  See the docs for [explicit register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Register-Variables.html).

Comment: @EOF: thats a real example: http://pastebin.com/kPALzZ5m. One correction: with -O3 gcc uses mla instruction, instead of MOVs and MUL. I had reproduced the behaviour with -frename-registers.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Ok, real example was with global register variables. I am updating the question text. Thanks.

Comment: The unoptimized code will never be efficient. GCC is generating inefficient code because that's what you told it do to.

Comment: @RossRidge IIRC, some optimizations are so simple they're done even at -O0. This could be expected to be one of them.

Comment: Copying the current rev of the OP source to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/PD9mXX), we see that using -O2, r8 and r9 get 2 and 3 assigned, and r0 has 5 assigned directly.  There is no extraneous assignments to r2 and r3.  The assignments to r8 and r9 cannot be removed since (as the docs say) "Stores into [globals] are never deleted even if they appear to be dead." I don't see how this can be any more efficient.

Comment: Thankyou guys. 

I ran suggestions presented here and found a better simple example (without data initialization)to clarify the question point: https://godbolt.org/g/isILcV

In fact, as said by @David, -O2 eliminate the 3rd and 4th MOV's.

I tried to obtain the exactly optimization used to generate this behaviour, but even using explicitly the O2 optimizations (`gcc -O2 -Q --help=optimizers |grep enabled`) I could not eliminate the 3rd and 4th MOV's.

Comment: There are no '3rd and 4th' MOVs in this godbolt code, there's only 1?  It does perform an (apparently) unnecessary load to r3 (instead of directly to r9), but I expect that's due to reading data from an uninitialized variable (vector).  Optimizing undefined behavior is probably hard.  Initializing the variable (`int vector[10] = {0};`) again produces optimal code.

Comment: arm is not a generic thing there are now many arm cores, three major instruction sets, which one are you talking about?   using a main function with completely dead code that normally just optimizes away, and using compiler specific tricks to use registers that make the code not function anyway, and then try to optimize and reduce the instrucitons.  just write assembly code and be done with it.  what is  it you are really trying to do?  just look at the gnu sources and figure it out if you really want to see how they work for that version that day...

Answer (score 2):

I took real example (posted in comments) and [put it on the godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:armhfg482,options:'-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-ffast-math+-Wa,-a,-ad',sourcez:MQSwZgBADAUATgUwOYgM4BcFwiAduiAQyNQFsAKAIjgA5KBKAbnmTU2zwICMSLqBOBs04RShPOXoQA3jAjyc%2BCAGNmCogF4ATGoVcNAZl3zlGwgGouxiInQBXOLhXMAvjBFgA9p/IA3TyAAJlLSNgj2jkSWjBBuwAi4geAwKSmguMoANnaBCBAAPBhJngB0ABYAfDDpWTl5heiBmSBc5VXVuWB4eQCyAIIAGgBKEACMUBMdCF24vYMAwmMTsMCd3RAAan0AMgCqAKIQAKxyKYgoGFiKBKh2pLwQVHAALEIsF%2BzXNg9PR2/nbCuImUP2oADZ/qxLhwlABrUFwADskI%2BQKUmFIAAdRgi6Ex3oCYQQMZitAjBPiAdCIJlPLgkBAnIQyI9qOM3iIAFSoODKUYAGgg3N5WkFnMCGGYMH8QRUhEyykkMjkEBJOI0Nk5uF0JLJGthWql8jVEA1avMsJ1CCxetV1tJ5lUKXkAHoXRAAJ6eOwQJDhCBcQiBFSeXIQLzYdBlNABhDKQh2VB5Hl8oiJCApsmERC%2B2mBzKoQW4TwEbNIVAQTHMpPBvBhcsq273DVNiDmDO80YAbTVAF0hR3lFoe/atL3XCkRGIJCIy8pBcoytmhWXfF3e/QYLJ5CJbFKVeBHnOIABCDVaEIq%2BRgTFwThgchFLBwQWUXZJgBcEAApBWAB6CgA7mUWB5H%2BGjKJ4Bb8nAniAagAA6uCUPyq5dlAG7WLYpoQAAtAYOgqi4EAIAWeTbgobqKJidgEGI6B3n%2BjIDE4qAgAAXggV6MjhGBwOgUHkGhoy9vyAByuzbNs/LjPi3GHuQJ7kI8uD5Bo/TDFIABkWkqWpGnzPQUiXuo8jYRq%2BFGNxxGkUmyqmRAbqkNanhwB6ojyrSyjcQ5vm%2BVR9GMV2nhgGASboP2GqBSAf7kC%2ByhSMBoEQCFYX%2BhqcUDrB8FSO23k%2BTgkDkI%2BnY4eQXJSGImReY%2BHEICF5X4PQWpakZpoahJUkmb5N53vgD5PnAL4QJQVVeUKwqps%2BrlIW8DluAVCklUOZUVR51WeIqbGcQ1nDNbgrVSBoHWSds3UOb196Po0z6vmNm0TZmJFDTNyH4vNBV%2BV9i1FeQEoEBla33VtdW7U1LW4G1x0QJ1Z32T1t5XYNw2jZ5D2cuKGDPbBcCze9pluBABVungIDoCA8ocYQ5N0g5BURo82AalAMTYPkjKs%2BY5jnaZDPkCCzMxCC7PaioXM8w5KbdnFrWOr2GhbHs%2BzWJLIpdjLkNywrOwHCrCiEwT3HE%2B6pB2Jk6AFa2gv065jOC98Iuc9z8MXbb/M4SzKgFBzYvOxRfl8/C9vwo7ECwuLLtfW6VsZncbaDtLcCy7CvaTcO5AGpryjjjAACQ6jxgqkh6%2BoBt%2Bf96tJ1nkWx6QJcKDHLOfbEBVl8bVHeugNEWw5bqI/1VAAAqwYEdjKOgH543rbp80z0Cs97otwBH/uUe64ZuwL89e6Hygr8b6j9%2BgD6UN%2BgQIegKEQBXGv0HL%2BPqFRsRE7369HyfU/Gwtr/OaQrnuWARAeQAAqAB5AAIqA50plzLz2skRU4ZlwgOCcHuGALggAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).  The main inefficiency in `calc()` is that `src1` and `src2` are globals it has to load from memory, instead of args passed in registers.

I didn't look at `main`, just `calc`.

```
register int sum asm ("r4");
register int r asm ("r5");
register int c asm ("r6");
register int k asm ("r7");
register int temp1 asm ("r8");    // really?  you're using two global register vars for scratch temporaries?  Just let the compiler do its job.
register int temp2 asm ("r9");
register long n asm ("r10");
int *src1, *src2, *dst;

void calc() {
  temp1 = r*n;
  temp2 = k*n;

  temp1 = temp1+k;
  temp2 = temp2+c;

  // you get bad code for this because src1 and src2 are globals, not args passed in regs
  sum = sum + src1[temp1] * src2[temp2];
}

    # gcc 4.8.2 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wa,-a,-ad -fverbose-asm
    mla     r0, r10, r7, r6          @ temp2.9, n, k, c   @@ tmp = k*n + c
    movw    r3, #:lower16:.LANCHOR0  @ tmp136,
    mla     r8, r10, r5, r7          @ temp1, n, r, k     @@ temp1 = r*n + k
    movt    r3, #:upper16:.LANCHOR0  @ tmp136,
    ldmia   r3, {r1, r2}             @ tmp136,,           @@ load both pointers, since they're stored adjacently in memory
    mov     r9, r0                   @ temp2, temp2.9     @@ This insn is wasted: the first MLA should have had this as the dest
    ldr     r3, [r1, r8, lsl #2]     @ *_22, *_22
    ldr     r2, [r2, r9, lsl #2]     @ *_28, *_28
    mla     r4, r2, r3, r4           @ sum, *_28, *_22, sum
    bx      lr                       @
```

For some reason, one of the integer multiply-accumulate (`mla`) instructions uses `r8` (`temp1`) as the destination, but the other one writes to `r0` (a scratch reg), and only later moves the result to `r9` (`temp2`).

The `sum +=  src1[temp1] * src2[temp2]` is done with an `mla` that reads and writes `r4` (`sum`).

**Why do you need `temp1` and `temp2` to be globals**?  That's just going to stop the optimizer from doing aggressive optimizations that don't calculate exactly the same temporaries that the C source does.  Fortunately the C memory model is weak enough that it should be able to reorder assignments to them, although this might actually be why it didn't MLA into `temp2` directly, since it decided to do that calculation first.  (Hmm, does the memory model even apply?  Other threads can't see our registers at all, so those globals are all effectively thread-local.  It should allow relaxed ordering for assignments to globals.  Signal handlers can see these globals, and could run at any point.  gcc isn't following strict source order, since in the source both multiplies happen before either add.)

Godbolt doesn't have a newer ARM gcc version, so I can't easily test a newer gcc.  A newer gcc might do a better job with this.

---

BTW, [I tried a version of the function using local variables for temporaries, and didn't actually get better results](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:armhfg482,options:'-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-ffast-math+-Wa,-a,-ad+-fverbose-asm+-frename-registers',sourcez:MQSwZgBADAUATgUwOYgM4BcFwiAduiAQyNQFsAKAIjgA5KBKAbnmTU2zwICMSLqBOBs04RShPOXoQA3jAjyc%2BCAGNmCogF4ATGoVcNAZl3zlGwgGouxiInQBXOLhXMAvjBFgA9p/IA3TyAAJlLSNgj2jkSWjBBuwAi4geAwKSmguMoANnaBCBAAPBhJngB0ABYAfDDpWTl5heiBmSBc5VXVuWB4eQCyAIIAGgBKEACMUBMdCF24vYMAwmMTsMCd3RAAan0AMgCqAKIQAKxyKYgoGFiKBKh2pLwQVHAALEIsF%2BzXNg9PR2/nbCuImUP2oADZ/qxLhwlABrUFwADsbwA9CjVtN1r5RtVwJ0INj3oCYQRMKQAA6jBF0JhE6FfMnkrQIwS0%2BKJZIA%2BmZTy4JAQJyEMiPajjN4iABUqDgylGABoIFKZVoFRLAhhmLiwPjCf4gipCJllJIZHIIIyqRobBLcLpGcyrbCbZr5BaIFaLeZYXaEBSHebfUzzKoUvI0RAAJ6eOwQJDhCBcQiBFSeXIQLzYdBlNAJhDKQh2VB5aWyoiJCAl5mERCxnmJzKoBW4TwEatIVAQclCovJvBhdtm273K1DiDmCsy0YAbQtAF1FRPlFoZ4GtLPXNUEkkwKk9cn80aAPo8g%2BH9AUk2yeQidCW61Ocfewd3Mcjycz0bziWL5dOh8qdcYDcGA9wNI8T0NM8KUPNtyQCfAsFQchlF5DAvileUU1wNDJVQLQQmfe5zBHac4BtMcIFhL8K1/cjx2UQC3CAA%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).  Probably because there are still so many register globals that gcc couldn't pick convenient regs for the temporaries.

```
// same register globals, except for temp1 and temp2.

void calc_local_tmp() {
  int t1 = r*n + k;
  sum += src1[t1] * src2[k*n + c];
}
    push    {lr}                      @ gcc decides to push to get a tmp reg
    movw    r3, #:lower16:.LANCHOR0   @ tmp131,
    mla     lr, r10, r5, r7           @ tmp133, n.1, r, k.2
    movt    r3, #:upper16:.LANCHOR0   @ tmp131,
    mla     ip, r7, r10, r6           @ tmp137, k.2, n.1, c
    ldr     r2, [r3]                  @ src1, src1
    ldr     r0, [r3, #4]              @ src2, src2
    ldr     r1, [r2, lr, lsl #2]      @ *_10, *_10
    ldr     r3, [r0, ip, lsl #2]      @ *_20, *_20
    mla     r4, r3, r1, r4            @ sum, *_20, *_10, sum
    ldr     pc, [sp], #4              @
```

Compiling with `-fcall-used-r8 -fcall-used-r9` didn't help; gcc makes the same code that pushes `lr` to get an extra temporary.  It fails to use `ldmia` (load-multiple) because it makes a sub-optimal choice of which temporary to put in which reg.  (`&src1` in `r0` would let it load `src1` and `src2` into `r2` and `r3`.)

Comment: thanks Peter! the main objective was to optimize a code in a simulated inorder cpu (gem5 arm minorcpu) that doesn't rename registers. This CPU has a limited organization (just one Multiplier, for example), so the attempt was increment this organization and put two independent blocks(set) of instructions, but without rename registers I need to force register independence. The code posted here was adapted to clarify the question, originally there isn't calc function e variables are local.

Comment: @GermanoAndersson: Do you actually get sub-optimal code with `-O3 -frename-registers`?  The gcc man page says that option does specifically optimize for CPUs that don't have hardware reg renaming.  Maybe also use `-mcpu=something_similar` to have gcc tune for an existing in-order CPU without reg renaming.

Comment: With -O3 gcc changes MOVs+MUL to MLA, so my optmization with organization changes in the minor cpu has no effect. I needed two block of instructions without dependences, resulting in parallel running when I add a Multiplier to organization.

Comment: @GermanoAndersson: Aren't there any existing ARM CPUs without an `MLA` instruction?  You can't in general make optimized code for your target architecture by making unoptimized code for a different architecture!  gcc uses `mla` even at `-O2`, which is the lowest generally-acceptable optimization level you should consider.  gcc is open-source, so you could in theory modify the machine definition for ARM in a custom gcc version.

Comment: @gma: Apparently [MLA is baseline](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihihggj.html), so there's no `-march` you can use to tell gcc not to use it in ARM mode.  It wasn't available in thumb mode until ARMv6T2, so [you can avoid it with `-march=armv5t -mthumb`](https://godbolt.org/g/HkCAeP), but then the asm only uses two-register instructions (e.g. `mov  r0, r10 / mul  r0, r5`).  Is that Thumb 1?  I'm not an ARM expert.